# How do I use COALESCE and JOIN at the same time and including NULL values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble using COALESCE and JOIN at the same time. My plan is:

- to match the *venture* column from my current table against the *vid* column from venture list table and return the corresponding venture name.
- if the *venture* column on the current table is zero (0) or null, the other column next to it will be selected (*"venture_other" column*)

Although my query returns its proper values, it seems like NULL values are ignored in this case.

**venture_list table:**

```
-------------------
| vid | name      |
-------------------
| 1   | Malaysia  |
-------------------
| 2   | Singapore |
-------------------
```

**request_forms:**

```
---------------------------------------------
| fid | username  | venture | venture_other |
---------------------------------------------
| 1   | jake.long | 2       |               |
---------------------------------------------
| 2   | xander.f  | 0       | Japan         |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Expected Result**

```
---------------
| venturename |
---------------
| Singapore   |
---------------
| Japan       |
---------------
```

**Actual Result**

```
---------------
| venturename |
---------------
| Singapore   |
---------------
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(ventures.name, null), venture_other) AS venturename
FROM request_forms forms
JOIN venture_list ventures ON ventures.vid = forms.venture
```

I tried rearranging the column names, but didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the links @Pang! I admit that I'm not very good in English (maybe just a little "good", hahaha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL default behaviour on a `JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN`.
Obviously since there is no matching result for the second row in `venture_list` you only get 1 row back.

Try using `LEFT JOIN` THAT way the column `ventures.name` will result in NULL and thus `venture_other` will be used.

Comment: This solution worked!  
I still need to learn more about JOIN. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your original use of NULLIF() here is peculiar. From the documentation:

> Returns NULL if expr1 = expr2 is true, otherwise returns expr1.

So your statement said, "In the event that ventures.name is NULL then return NULL else return ventures.name". Which is superfluous since a NULL will already return a NULL because it's NULL.

Instead of the case, and properly using the `NULLIF()` you could have the `NULLIF()` return a NULL in the event that ventures.name is `0`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(ventures.name, 0), venture_other) AS venturename
FROM request_forms forms
JOIN venture_list ventures ON ventures.vid = forms.venture
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close but need to change the nullif a bit:

```
select coalesce(nullif(ventures.name,0), venture_other) as venturename
  from request_forms forms
  join venture_list ventures
    on ventures.vid = forms.venture;
```

Basically, you want to use nullif to null out ventures.name if it is 0..then the coalesce does the rest.

Comment: I don't know why this solution doesn't work on me. Thanks by the way.